# Jquery identification of program syntax

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Is there any jquery Plugin:1.which can identify a programing language and highlight its syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not jquery-based, but [google code prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) is a fairly commonly used script for this purpose.

Comment: As listed on the project page, it's released under the Apache License 2.0: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Answer (score 3):

Another good highlighter is the [Syntax Higlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/). It is JavaScript based.