# jquery plugin syntax identifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

Any jquery tool for code identifier.i.e,the plugin should identify the language keywords for c,c++..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery identification of program syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301938/jquery-identification-of-program-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of [Codemirror](http://codemirror.net/) (or just using it) might give you some pointers

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you want to use it? Here are a couple of things that might help:

SyntaxHighlighter: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

beauty Of Code: http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2008/10/30/beautyofcode-jquery-plugin-for-syntax-highlighting/